# Where one can get file /dev/lvm-disk/debian-bullseye-arm64?

Tags: partition, lvm, qemu

In QEMU example it is said to use option

```
-blockdev driver=raw,node-name=hd,file.driver=host_device,file.filename=/dev/lvm-disk/debian-bullseye-arm64
```

Apparently, this device expected to exist under `/dev`

I don't have anything similar there.

What is this file kind and how one can create it?

If it is a physical partition, how can I create one on my machine assuming all disks are already formatted? Can I use loopback device for this?

Comment: According to the name it seems to be a lvm partition. `If it is a physical partition, how can I create one on my machine assuming all disks are already formatted? Can I use loopback device for this?` I might be wrong but I think qemu doesn't really __need__ a block device, you could just create a file of a specific size and pass that as argument instead.

Comment: I would say `lvm-disk` is an lvm volume group (VG) in this example and `debian-bullseye-arm64` is a logical volume (LV) in that volume group - neither of those names are "special", i.e. they have no specific meaning and could just as easily be `/dev/foo/bar` if you have a `foo` VG with a `wilma` LV - where is that example from? did you read the whole thing?